# How do I maintain the user credentials when each request can hit multiple servers

Tags: java, database, servlet-listeners

Say I have logged into amazon.com. there are say 5 servers present to handle the traffic. Every request from my end hits say Amazon's server 1. Now there are many users coming to picture and my every request can go to server 2 or server 3. How do you make sure that servers two and three communicate communicate with one for my login details??
Which would be the best way to handle it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

- Go for a Standalone Authentication and Authorization server.
- Any incoming request should first be validated by Authentication
  server and then processed.
- Authentication and authorization mechanism will probably be Token
  Based using OAUth.
- To keep things like user preferences etc which expire with the
  session, you will probably need a seperate In-memory DB server.

Comment: Never thought of Token based oauth. Now my question is if I keep the oauth in cookie then is it a good idea if I have to make a call to the db for user pref for every single request? Is there any other way I can keep user pref without having to make db call

Comment: I would suggest going through the below links. That should make things clear. Incase your still have any doubts, feel free to drop an email to me: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/